# Upload video on Twitter without 3rd library

Tags: c#, video, twitter

I use Hammock in the project and I want to upload videos to Twitter. I also get the "media type unrecognized" error when I try with the following code. Where part am I doing wrong?

```
        var restClient = new Hammock.RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://upload.twitter.com",
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        };

        var restRequest = new Hammock.RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = "/1.1/media/upload.json",
            Method = Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        };

        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(images);
        restRequest.AddFile("media", "test", stream);

        var asyncResult = restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest);
        var response = restClient.EndRequest(asyncResult);
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Image>(response.Content);
```

Comment: I can't test anything because I don't have twitter keys, but [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/chunked-media-upload) says video/gifs need to be uploaded in chunks. and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tweeting-using-logic-apps-error-media-type-unrecognized-when-sending-image-wi/) says you need to upload as a binary stream.

Comment: I solved the problem. I can upload the file, but I can't upload a file of 1mb or larger. it gives an error.
However, I can upload files under 1mb.

Comment: that's strange because twitter's documentation says videos can be up to 15MB. I would look into chunking the data if you want to upload files larger than 1MB

Comment: When I upload a 2 MB file, it gives "Segments do not add up to provided total file size."

Comment: I split the file this way

`const int chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
 using (var filex = File.OpenRead(gallery.MediaUrl))
 {
  int bytesRead, chunkID = 0;
  var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
  while ((bytesRead = filex.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
 {
 if (bytesRead < chunkSize)
 {
 var lastBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, lastBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
 buffer = new byte[bytesRead];
 buffer = lastBuffer;
 }
 try
 {
 //ServiceCall
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Console.WriteLine($"[ERROR] {ex.Message}");
 return;
 }
 chunkID++;
 }
}`